# How can I show two animated plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to animate two different plots with matplotlib in python, but all is not going well.

I started with one plot and that was fine. Animation was easy enough. But now I want to add a second animated line plot, and I'm struggling. I'd like three lines on that second plot. Do I need to have one figure with two subplots? Or do I need to have two figures, and have a sub-plot to represent each of the three lines on the second figure?

I figured I need to create two animations and introduce sub-plots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
animation1 = FuncAnimation(fig, self.animate_first, numframes, repeat = False, interval = 10, blit = True)
animation2 = FuncAnimation(fig, self.animate_linegraph, numframes, repeat = False, interval = 10, blit = True)
```

but if subplots returns a single figure object, and that is the first parameter to FuncAnimation, what should the animate callback functions do? When I only had one plot to display, I returned the list of patches from the animate function. But when I have two plots to update. I'm not sure what to do.

Any pointers greatly appreciated. Oh (and in case it wasn't obvious :) ), I am completely new to python.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: It's not too clear what you mean by "plot" here. Do you want to have two lines in the same axes being animated? Or two lines in two different axes ("subplots")? Or two lines in different axes from different figures?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want to have two figures - one showing an animation of circles moving - that is working fine. I now want to add another graph to show alongside the circle animation. This new graph I want to have showing 3 lines depicting 3 different types of energy on the y axis, and time on the x-axis. I'd like the x-axis to move too - so it might show 0 to 10 minutes, but as the lines move along I'd like the x-axis move too, so maybe show 1 to 11 mins, 2 to 12, 3 to 13 etc.

Comment: If you have 2 figures, `fig1` and `fig2` you can create two `FuncAnimations`, one for each figure. You can equally create a single `FuncAnimation` and still use it to update a different figure. I do not see clear on what problem you face (which is most likely because you do not share the code that produces the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved subplot animations in the past along the following lines:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
    title = plt.title('')
    title.set_text('')
    return fig,ax2,ax3,title

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):

    a = ax2.pcolor(x,y,data)

    b = ax3.pcolor(x2,y2,data2)

    main_title.set_text('Main Title')
    title2.set_text('Sub title 1')
    title3.set_text('Sub title 2')

    return main_title, title2, title3, ax2, ax3

# call the animator.
fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
title2 = ax2.set_title('')
title3 = ax3.set_title('')
main_title = fig.suptitle('')


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=101, interval=250, blit=False)


anim.save('file.mp4', writer=writer)
plt.close()
```

Not sure if this is helpful, it's mostly copy and paste from an old script I haven't used in a while...